# How to filter Pandas rows by another Dataframe columns?

Tags: python

Say I have two Pandas dataframes like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['asdf'], ['zxcv'], ['qwer'], ['hjkl']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['b','0'],['asdf','1'],['c','2'],['hjkl','3']])
```

How to I filter out df2 to only contain rows if it has a value from df1?

I want to get a dataframe like this from the operation

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['asdf','1'], ['hjkl', '3']])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of merging:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2)
#      0  1
#0  asdf  1
#1  hjkl  3
```